# Copiando strings em C

Tags: c, c++, string, char

Eu gostaria de um ajuda na seguinte questão:

Eu tenho um `char` com um texto de 32 caracteres, então eu gostaria de saber como fazer para separar este `char` em dois de 16 caracteres.

Tipo:

```
char textao[32] = "Oi meu nome e Cesar tudo bem ai?"
```

E tem que ficar:

```
char textoInicio[16] = "Oi meu nome e Ce"
char textoFim[16] = "sar tudo bem ai?"
```

Eu usei `strncpy(textoInicio, textao, 16)` para a primeira parte e deu certo. Agora não sei como fazer para a segunda. Também não queria usar `for`.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, em C você sempre precisa de um espaço adicional no seu array porque as strings precisam de um caractere nulo(que pode ser representado com `0` ou `'\0'`) pra indicar onde elas acabam. E pra copiar uma string a partir de um ponto, basta usar o operador `&` pra retornar o endereço de memória do local especifico que você quer copiar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char textao[33] = "Oi meu nome e Cesar tudo bem ai?";
    char textoInicio[17];
    char textoFim[17];

    /*copiando texto*/
    strncpy(textoInicio, textao, 16);
    textoInicio[16] = 0;

    strncpy(textoFim, &textao[16], 16);
    textoFim[16] = 0;

    printf("inicio: %s\n", textoInicio);
    printf("Fim: %s", textoFim);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Ossetian_Odin. Funcionou perfeitamente. :D